# What's the function $1+\sin(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x)^2 \cos(x)^2 + \cdot \cdot \cdot$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

What's the function determined by the series $1+\sin(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x)^2 \cos(x)^2 + \cdot \cdot \cdot$?

---

Note, the series converges uniformly.

Comment: Think of a geometric series.

Comment: $sin(x^2)$or $(sinx)^2$?

Comment: @Khosrotash $(\sin(x))^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{\sin2x}2$  and $-1\le\sin2x\le1$  for real $x$

$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty ar^n=\dfrac a{1-r}$$  for $|r|<1$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\quad{\text{ for }}|x|<1$$

---

*Let $x\to\sin x\cos x$.*

Comment: Of course. But is this some "well-known" function? Applied somewhere perhaps?

Comment: @mavavilj does a function need to be "well-known" or applicable to some situation in order for it to be well understood or useful?  $\frac{1}{1-\sin(x)\cos(x)}$ is as simplified as they come...